# Continuous random variable and the normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

How are we going to know that a continuous random variable is a normal random variable? The definition I believe for a continuous r.v. to be a normal r.v. is that it's probability density function must be the pdf of the normal distribution. How are we going to check the pdf of a continuous r.v. and compare it with the normal distribution?

I really need the help. Thanks guys.

Comment: What is your rv?

Comment: Just some random continuous rv. I'm trying to find whether there exist a procedure that one must do in order to check whether a continuous rv is a normal rv or not.

Comment: It sounds like: how to find out that a piece of fruit is an apple?

Comment: Do you have an equation? Dataset? Without more information, not much to be done. Maybe graph a histogram of your data and fit it with the normal pdf. Try a statistical test, like KS-test, which compares the cdf.

Comment: Compare the pdf of your rv with $\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \textrm{exp}\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right]$

Comment: @drhab Yup. That hits the mark.

Comment: @jdods All I have is the knowledge that it is a continuous rv. So do I need a data set? Should gathering some data be included in the procedure that I'm looking for?

Comment: @thesimplifire How am I going to produce the pdf of a continuous rv?

Comment: @Issac have you learnt about characteristic function? Some times the characteristic function are more easy to verify a random variable. See https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/characteristic.pdf

Comment: @truski Nope. I havent learned about it yet. Can I use the idea of a characteristic func to check whether its underlying pdf is the normal distribution?

Comment: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~ccanonne/files/misc/2015-survey-distributions.pdf

This document is a survey on 'testing' distributions. What is important is that it focuses on methods that have provable guarantees.

What might be relevant to you is the chapters on testing closeness between distributions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have certain data regarding your specific random variable, one of the methods to deduce its distribution is the so called statistical inference, where you try to find the distribution (and respective pdf) that best fits your data. Sometimes you're only interested in some properties of the random variable, like its mean or variance, and not necessarily the distribution itself.

There are parametric and nonparametric approaches to this, you should check these definitions carefully.

Comment: Can you site a reference where I can do some readings this Statistical Inference? I'm really interested in nailing if it is a normal rv or not.

Comment: The book 'All of Statistics' by Larry A. Wasserman is pretty good.

Comment: Does this book specifically tackle the issue that Im facing here. Do you happen to have an electronic copy of it? :)

Comment: It might provide you with an insight on what's behind statistical inference. If your issue is simply comparing the pdfs, then you do it directly by looking at both of them. No I don't.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for your help :)